# How to convert List to Map and make the map key the object's attributes

Tags: java, spring-boot

If I have a class Transaction:

```html
public class Transaction {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    
    private String customerName;
    
    private String phoneNumber;
    
    //...getters and setters
    
    }
```

and I find the transactions by customerName via Spring Repository:

```html
    List<Transaction> findByCustomerName(String customerName);
```

I then want to convert the list of Transactions to a map, using the following code, but instead of a specific value, is there a way to make the Map's Keys be the object attributes?

```html
Map<Long, Transaction> transactionMap = transactionList.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(Transaction::getId, Function.identity()));
```

So instead of the specific id for that Transaction object, at Transaction::getId, I would just want it to be the string attribute "Id", but I would want it to be whatever attribute it is in the list... so the next attribute to a Transaction would be customerName, so it wouldnt show "Id" it should show "customerName"

Comment: post a sample of intended output

Comment: Sorry the question is a bit vague to me. Are you saying that you want the Key to be dynamic based on whatever attribute is available on your Transaction Object?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want is shown as follows, I assumed that there is a default constructor in class `Transaction` with its fields.

**Code snippet**

```
Transaction t1 = new Transaction(10L, "AAA", "0987654321");
Transaction t2 = new Transaction(20L, "BBB", "0901234567");

List<Transaction> transactionList = new ArrayList<>();
transactionList.add(t1);
transactionList.add(t2);

// Use id as the key
Map<Long, Transaction> transactionMap1 = transactionList.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(Transaction::getId, Function.identity()));
System.out.println(transactionMap1.toString());

// Use customerName as the key
Map<String, Transaction> transactionMap2 = transactionList.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(Transaction::getCustomerName, Function.identity()));
System.out.println(transactionMap2.toString());
```

**Console output**

> {20=Transaction [id=20, customerName=BBB, phoneNumber=0901234567], 10=Transaction [id=10, customerName=AAA, phoneNumber=0987654321]}
>   {AAA=Transaction [id=10, customerName=AAA, phoneNumber=0987654321], BBB=Transaction [id=20, customerName=BBB, phoneNumber=0901234567]}